# percona xtradb cluster mysql startup error

Tags: mysql, centos, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster

i have 2 nodes to prepare percona xtradb cluster , i have successfully installed the applications . then I tried to configure the file my.cnf
NODE1 :

```
cat >>/etc/my.cnf<<EOF
[mysqld]
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera3/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name=democluster
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.254.126,192.168.254.127
wsrep_node_name=centosvm02
wsrep_node_address=192.168.254.126
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup-v2
wsrep_sst_auth=uertest:123abc@A
pxc_strict_mode=ENFORCING
binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
EOF
```

NODE 2 :

```
cat >>/etc/my.cnf<<EOF
[mysqld]
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera3/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name=democluster
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.254.126,192.168.254.127
wsrep_node_name=centosvm02
wsrep_node_address=192.168.254.127
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup-v2
wsrep_sst_auth=uertest:123abc@A
pxc_strict_mode=ENFORCING
binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
EOF
```

after config is done i started systemctl start mysql@bootstrap but it failed. I discovered an error on startup
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg141.png)

Comment: Please ask database admin related questions on the dedicated DBA sister-site of SO, not here, on the programming focused SO!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear. The needed library cannot be found. If you installed PXC 8, then the library is galera4, not galera3. Make sure you installed all appropriate packages.